# Конструкторы по умолчанию в списке инициализации для простых типов

Tags: c++, конструктор

Вопрос в следующем:

```
class A
{
    public:
    A(){}
    private;
    int value;
};
```

Во время вызова конструктора `A()`, будет ли вызван конструктор по умолчанию для `A::value`?

Будет ли `A::value` инициализирован нулем?

Comment: Если написать список инициализации, то будет.

Comment: И где тот список инициализации, который указан в заголовке вопроса?

Answer (score 3):

У `A::value` нет никаких конструкторов. Тип `int` не является класс-типом и конструкторов иметь не может.

Инициализация для полей не-класс типов в составе класса идет по своим, довольно разветвленным правилам. В данном случае - когда вы явно предоставили свой конструктор для класса `A`, но при этом никак не позаботились о поле `value` - поле `A::value` в общем случае будет получать непредсказуемое значение.

Инициализация нулем в этом случае произойдет только в том случае, если объект класса `A` объявлен со статическим классом памяти. Но эта инициализация уже не имеет никакого отношения к конструкторам.

Answer (score 2):

У простых типов нет конструкторов по умолчанию, их память ничем не инициализируется. Но можно делать так:

```
class A
{
    public:
    A(){}
    private;
    int value = 0;
};
```

Comment: В варианте `struct A { int value; } a = {};` поле `a.value` получит значение `0`. Так что "их память ничем не инициализируется" - слишком сильное утверждение. В общем случае поведение может зависеть от внешних факторов.

Answer (score 1):

Переменные статические **g** будут записаны в код с обнулением. Локальные переменные **a / *pa** будут в стеке/куче и конструктор для **int** будет по умолчанию осутствовать (с мусором).

```
class A
{
    public:
    A(){}
private:
    int value;
};
A g;
int main(){
A a;
A * pa = new A();}
```